# Android master / detail fragment with back button

Tags: android

I implemented a Drawer in the Main FragmentActivity, but don't know how to add a back navigation button in master/detail fragment.... Find several days still no answer.... any expert can help?

```
>> MainActivity with Drawer
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerList;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            CreateMenuItem();
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            // Handle action bar actions click
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        private void displayView(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:     
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame, FragmentA.newInstance(), FragmentA.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame, FragmentB.newInstance(), FragmentB.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame, FragmentC.newInstance(), FragmentC.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_frame, FragmentD.newInstance(), FragmentD.TAG).commit();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }   
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }   
    }

>> Fragment A (Master Fragment)
    public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

        public FragmentA(){}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentA, container, false);
            Button button= (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    FragmentDetail fd = new FragmentDetail();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentdetail, fd);
                    ft.setTransition(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }

>> FragmentDetail (Detail Fragment) > How to add a back button instead the navigator drawer menu  
    public class FragmentDetail extends Fragment {   
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);        
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

I implemented a Drawer in the Main FragmentActivity, but don't know how to add a back navigation button in master/detail fragment.... Find several days still no answer.... any expert can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/**
     * Handling back press of all fragments (Use this in fragmentactivity)
     * 
     * */

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
 super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually set an onKeyListener to the View in onResume. From what I learned you have to take care to set **setFocusableInTouchMode()** and requestFocus on the View.

This is a sample of what I use for this purpose:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                // handle back button

                 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```